# How to specify an optional property inside another optional property?

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to specify optional property postalCode inside another optional property place in my Conference interface, but I get an error when I try to do it like that:

```
export interface Conference {
  name: string;
  subject: string;
  description: string;
  lecturer: string;
  type: string;
  linkToMeeting: string;
  place?: Place;
  date: string;
  time: string;
  participantsLimited: string;
}

export interface Place {
  address: string;
  city: string;
  postalCode?: string;
  country: string;
}
```

The error I receive:

```
Type 'Conference' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; subject: string; description: string; lecturer: string; type: string; place: { address: string; city: string; country: string; postalCode?: undefined; }; linkToMeeting: string; date: string; time: string; participantsLimited: string; }'.
    Types of property 'place' are incompatible.
      Type 'Place | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ address: string; city: string; country: string; postalCode?: undefined; }'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ address: string; city: string; country: string; postalCode?: undefined; }'.
```

I can a use workaround such as specifying postalCode property as "postalCode?: any", but there must be an option to specify it as a "string" and optional property.

Comment: The type definitions look fine. What code (presumably an assignment statement) is showing the error?

Comment: Can you post the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: [Works in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiXTWCVzgG8AoOOJTAW2AC44BnGKZAcwG5acMABscwAPxsACqNwCAvtWqhIsRCjRYKMsVUGYAJgajB27Np25J+gyJ0zDCBiRa68FS7EU70mwAPJIwgCebITEpOR4ALx6dAzMbADk6BAQSdTyAtReSD4JwACCSAaFRiZmgSFhRCQmUXCxNPF+yanpADS2sqxxdHCGxqbmcEkARphQGXSKWZ7e8AXFpcLCNRH1FE2CBW1pSV10ImJszf2DFSPjkweCRxD2jhDOyRMAXtNws9m5+X7LADkAK6rdZ1MhbPq7UbtW5HHqnO4DcrDV43Q79OwwBxOXpIEHCQTfIA), so +1 to 'show the code' preach. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was a dumb mistake of mine. There was no problem with the interfaces I specified. They are ok. It was a problem with me trying to push new conference to some arrays that didn't have a specified type Conference[]. Thank you all for comments and reassuring me that the interface specification was fine.